# Counting items within indexed map

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

How do you index and count items within an indexed map?  Here's an example -
I have example JSON data that looks like this -

```
[ {
 "id" : "z1",
"content_type" : "single",
"item_1" : "000"
}, {
"id" : "z2",
"content_type" : "double",
"item_1" : "bing",
"item_2" : "bong"
}, {
 "id" : "z3",
"content_type" : "triple",
"item_1" : "tttt",
"item_2" : "toooo",
"item_3": "tiii"
}, {
"id" : "z4",
"content_type" : "double",
"item_1" : "111",
"item_2" : "222"
}]
```

Going into a component that looks like this -

```
   [:div.scroller 
      (doall
       (map-indexed
        (fn [index coll]
         (condp = (:content_type coll)
          "single" ^{:key (str index)}[:div (str (:item_1 coll))]
          "double" ^{:key (str index)}[:div 
                                [:div (str (:item_1 coll))][:div (str (:item_2 coll))]
                                       [:div (str index)]]
          )) collections))]
```

This gives me an index for each grouping, which is needed for ordering and referencing however I would also like a index and count of each individual item within those collections i.e "000" "bing" "bong" etc to be [0 "000"] [1 "bing"] [2 "bong]

Comment: Why is it `[2 "bong"]` - it's neither 2 for a count nor is 2 the correct index (it's in the second map, therefor 1)?

Comment: It was just an example of all the items being counted together - i.e anything in an item_n is counted consecutively

Comment: So you want to mapcat all `item_n` values and then add an index?

Comment: While also displaying them in their separate collections in divs as laid out in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `str` in any of those cases. Also, since your constants are literals, you can replace `(condp = ...)` with `(case ...)` (add `nil` at the end if you don't want it to throw on a missing clause).

As for the question, it seems that you need to restructure the input data so every map has both the content type and exactly one item.
You can do so like this:

```
(into []
      (mapcat (fn [m]
                (let [ct (:content_type m)]
                  (map (fn [v]
                         {:content_type ct
                          :item         v})
                       (vals (dissoc m :id :content_type))))))
      data)
```

If you need to maintain the grouping but number each item within every group independently of the groups, this is how you can do it:

```clj
(defn group-items [m]
  {:id           (:id m)
   :content_type (:content_type m)
   :items        (vec (vals (dissoc m :id :content_type)))})

(defn index-items-by-idx [m offset]
  (update m :items (fn [items]
                     (zipmap (map #(+ offset %) (range))
                             items))))

(let [data [{:id           "z1"
             :content_type "single"
             :item_1       "000"}
            {:id           "z2"
             :content_type "double"
             :item_1       "bing"
             :item_2       "bong"}
            {:id           "z3"
             :content_type "triple"
             :item_1       "tttt"
             :item_2       "toooo"
             :item_3       "tiii"}
            {:id           "z4"
             :content_type "double"
             :item_1       "111"
             :item_2       "222"}]]
  (first (reduce (fn [[acc offset] m]
                   (let [m (-> m
                               (group-items)
                               (index-items-by-idx offset))]
                     [(conj acc m)
                      (+ offset (count (:items m)))]))
                 [[] 0]
                 data)))

=>
[{:id "z1", :content_type "single", :items {0 "000"}}
 {:id "z2", :content_type "double", :items {1 "bing", 2 "bong"}}
 {:id "z3", :content_type "triple", :items {3 "tttt", 4 "toooo", 5 "tiii"}}
 {:id "z4", :content_type "double", :items {6 "111", 7 "222"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for looking - for styling and layout purposes I still need to treat them all as separate groupings and content_type is not necessarily unique

Comment: I've added that case to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like I'm missing something very basic now;  since I've lost my keyed reference to each item how can I lay them out as before

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keyed reference", but I can tell you for certain that you should not be using item indices as React's `key`. You seem to have an organic `:id` - use that instead. If you meant things like `:item_1`, then you can easily transform my code above so that instead of a map of items it has e.g. a vector of indes+item, and then each idx+item is just a `(get m [:items 0])` away. Or you can have two vectors, or a vector of maps, or you can add an index to each item by having keys like `:item_1_index`.

Comment: yes, I think my question was unclear, but as seen in the reagent layout I am using the symbols to reference specific parts.

Comment: I don't understand the code you've written well enough to make those kinds of changes

Comment: The code above is very, very simple. I'd definitely suggest stopping by the Clojurians Slack server and joining the `#beginners` channel.